# VS2017 in DEBUG mode throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

If I run outside debug mode (e.g. Ctrl-F5) then it works fine and I can log in. When I'm in debug mode I get a nullreference error on the line:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

However, if I put a stop point on that line, then model.UserName and model.RememberMe both have values and a debug assist line of `var test1 = FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl;` shows that `FormsAuthentication` exists.

It's obviously fairly crucial that I run my code in debug mode to see what is happening in critical parts of the code, so this is a bit of a blocker.

Is it something to do with the way VS2017 launches chrome debug sessions with different command line parameters?  I'm clutching at straws here.

Edited to add: Same problem happens if I debug with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Hmm. Well if I add `targetFramework="4.7.1" ` to my `httpruntime` in web.config then it works fine in debug mode.

Comment: Ah. But that then breaks the cookie decryption as the cookie is set by a 4.0 website!  Welcome to VS2017, eh...?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be a problem but here is an article about sharing Auth cookies between 4.x and .net core which may contain some relevant info: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SharingAuthorizationCookiesBetweenASPNET4xAndASPNETCore10.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I finally got both things working by including `compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2"` in my `machinekey` entry in web.config.  This allows latest framework stuff to run but still use old compatibility.